# knpmenubundle: How to get user data in builder?

Tags: php, symfony, knpmenubundle

How can I get User data in the`KnpMenuBundle`'s Builder?

I know I can get the user data via this line in Controller:

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

but I want it to get in my menu builder aswell, so I can put the username in the menu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your MenuBuilder is defined as a service in Symfony2, as you can see in
https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/menu_service.rst

Basically, all you need to do is configure your MenuBuilder service definition to inject the security context. (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services)

Answer (score 9):

Simshaun is totaly right. After some research i manage to do it like this :

1. Add the injection on `services.yml` :

   ```
   administration_main.menu.main:
     class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem
     factory_service: administration_main.menu_builder
     factory_method: createAdministrationMainMenu
     arguments: ["@request","@security.context"]
     scope: request
     tags:
         - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: administrationMain }
   ```
2. Use it on the menu builder

   ```
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

   public function createAdministrationMainMenu(Request $request, SecurityContext $securityContext){

     $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

   }
   ```